# Receiving Caught exception: Error: listen EACCES while running gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, node.js-connect

I am using gulp in my project. I would like to start the `node` server via  a gulp task.

This is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var server = require('gulp-develop-server');

gulp.task('server:start', ['scripts'], function() {
  server.listen({
      path: '/home/ubuntu/node-v0.10.33/TestApp/app.js',
  });
});

// restart server if app.js changed 
gulp.task('server:restart', function() {
   gulp.watch(['/home/ubuntu/node-v0.10.33/TestApp/app.js'], server.restart);
});

gulp.task('default', ['server:start']);
```

My node port number is `80`.
And I am running this code in Ubuntu server:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~/gulpReact$ gulp
[12:32:35] Using gulpfile ~/gulpReact/gulpfile.js

[12:32:35] Starting 'server:start'...
[12:32:35] Finished 'server:start' after 3.27 ms
[12:32:35] Starting 'default'...
[12:32:35] Finished 'default' after 7.9 μs
[12:32:35] Development server listening. (PID:7653)
Caught exception: Error: listen EACCES
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're either

- Running two servers on the same port (:`80`), try running `sudo netstat -tulpn` to see which processes are currently listening
- Not running `gulp` with `sudo` (apparently an issue under *nix)

Other than that, `gulp-liveconnect` may or may not run on the same port.

You can also try binding to another interface address, e.g. `*` or `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`.